# Find specific string then special character after string and integers

Tags: vb.net, find, special-characters

Ok this is a spin on a question I asked before, although i dont think I was clear enough in my explanation.  My example strings are as follows.

```
06:15:34GET/a/users/23/list_messageHTTP

06:15:35PUT/a/users/231223/badge?HTTP

06:15:36POST/a/users/4454?set_action
```

I am trying to search for example "POST/a/users/" or "GET/a/users/"  then find the next special character after the number/integers.  So for the last example you can see there is ?, that is what im trying to locate to enable me to put a vbtab before it.

I can for instance find the 4th / in a line and put a vbtab before it but not find a string then find the next special character after it.

Any help is gratefully received, many thanks VBVirg

Comment: Should be very quick and easy to do with regular expressions.... As a starting off point, check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace-vbnet  or  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Because there are so many variables it makes it difficult to find, however if I did a find of GET/a/users/ then some how do the equivalent of a a Ctrl Right that would skip the integers and go to /list_messageHTTP where i could preceed it with a vbtab.  But is using the equivalent of a Ctrl Right bad practice if it could even be done?

Comment: I truly don't understand. Have you looked into it? - Regex can do exactly what you want. For example, the pattern `GET\/a\/users\/.*?([\/\?])` would return the special character following the "GET/a/users/" statement. Then you just do a `regex.replace`....

Comment: Apologies John i will review again, im completely new to VB and Regex.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi John, thanks so much, im loving Regex all new to me but great fun thank you for your help.  Kind Regards VBVirg